# Почему кириллица в базе данных отображается иероглифами?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include "bd.php";
if(isset($_POST['go_add']))
{
    if (isset($_POST['title']))        {$title = $_POST['title']; if ($title == '') {unset($title);}}
    if (isset($_POST['date']))        {$date = $_POST['date']; if ($date == '') {unset($date);}}
    if (isset($_POST['description'])) {$description = $_POST['description']; if ($description == '') {unset($description);}}
    if (isset($_POST['text']))        {$text = $_POST['text']; if ($text == '') {unset($text);}}
    if (isset($_POST['author']))      {$author = $_POST['author']; if ($author == '') {unset($author);}}
    if (isset($_POST['id']))      {$id = $_POST['id'];}


    if ($_POST['title'] != "" &&
        $_POST['date'] != "" &&
        $_POST['description'] != "" &&
        $_POST['author'] != "" )
    {
        if (mysql_query ("INSERT INTO data SET
                title='".$title."',
                description='".$description."',
                text='".$text."',
                author='".$author."'"))
        {
            echo "<div class='clean-ok'>Новость успешно добавлена!<br>
                  <a href='/admin/index.php?f=news&mod=add'>Добавить ещё.</a></p></div>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<div class='clean-gray'>Неудалось обработать базой<div>";
            $dar = mysql_error();
            echo $der;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div class='clean-error'><p>Незаполнена вся инфа.</p></div>";
    }
}
?>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="">

  <p>
    Введите название <br>
    <input type="text"  style="border:1px silver solid; width:160px;" name="title" id="title">
   </p>
   <p>
    Введите автора <br>
    <input name="author" style="border:1px silver solid; width:160px;" type="text" id="author" value="Admin" >
   </p>
    Введите дату добавления <br>
    <input name="date"  style="border:1px silver solid; width:160px;" type="text" id="datepicker"
           value="<?php $date = date("d/m/Y"); echo $date; ?>">
    <br>
  <p>
    Краткая новость<br>
    <textarea style="width:650px; height:240px;" name="description" cols="80" >   </textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    Полная новость<br>
    <textarea style="width:650px; height:260px;"  name="text"  cols="80" ></textarea>
  </p>
  <input type="submit" class="buttons" name="go_add"  id="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: Приведите в соответствие кодировку текста в запросе и кодировку таблиц в БД

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, то кодировка страницы на UTF-8 без BOM, и при подключение к БД 
    
     mysql_query("SET NAMES CP1251");

Comment: @lifting, если страница в UTF-8, то mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");

Comment: dekameron, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев:*

MySQL по умолчанию ожидает, что клиент будет отправлять данные в кодировке latin1 (это связано с тем, что MySQL изначально шведская разработка). Даже если кодировка вашей базы данных UTF-8, даже если вы отправляете данные в UTF-8, она будет пытаться преобразовать latin1 в utf8. Это, конечно, приводит к искажению русского текста. Для того, чтобы предотвратить это необходимо явно сообщить, в какой кодировке вы будете отправлять данные. В случае UTF-8 сделать это можно при помощи следующего запроса

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
```